# Evaluate Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Fourier series is quite a new concept for me and I'm not sure if I understand them correctly.

I am given a function $f:[-\pi, \pi] \to \mathbb{R} $ defined by

$$
x\mapsto
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $-\pi \le x \le -\pi /2$} \\
1 & \text{if $-\pi/2 \lt x \le \pi /2$} \\
0 & \text{if $\pi/2 \lt x \le \pi$}
\end{cases}
$$

the function is extended periodically to the whole of $ \mathbb{R} $, and has the Fourier series, $S_f(x)$. And I am supposed to evaluate $S_f(\frac{\pi}{2})$, and this is the part I am struggling with. So far I have found that the Fourier series for this function is (I might be wrong though):
$$S_f(x)= \frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi n} \sin\Big(\frac{\pi n}{2}\Big) \cdot \sin(nx) $$ but after this part, I am stuck.

Comment: Do you know Dirichlet's theorem about convergence of Fourier series? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions

Comment: This is an even function so must be a sum of cosines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Dirichlet's theorem, the answer is $\frac{f\left( \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^+\right) + f\left( \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^-\right)}{2}=\frac12$.

But let's verify it, you made a minor mistake in your series  expression, rather than sines, it should be cosines.

$$S_f(x)= \frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi n} \sin\Big(\frac{\pi n}{2}\Big) \cdot \color{red}\cos(nx) $$

Hence

$$S_f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi n} \sin\Big(\frac{\pi n}{2}\Big) \cdot \cos\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right) =\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(n\pi\right)}{\pi n} =\frac12 + 0=\frac12$$